# jquery select by data- value that is a variable

Tags: jquery, html, variables, select

I'm having trouble applying answers from similar questions to my situation and I think it is because the value I'm looking for is a variable and not a constant string like most others.

I have a variable `activeSlide` equal to the active slide: 1, 2, or 3.  I want the button whose `data-dir = activeSlide` to show bold text but I can't seem to select the button based on the data- value.  I can select an exact slide number with:

```
$('btns [data-dir=2]')...
```

But replacing 2 with `activeSlide` or `#{activeSlide}` isn't yielding any results.  I'm about to re-write all my code with classes instead of the data- that is confusing me!  Before I do that would someone mind showing me how I can select the button whose data-dir=activeSlide ?

html:

```html
<div class='btns'>
  <button data-dir='1'>1</button>
  <button data-dir='2'>2</button>
  <button data-dir='3'>3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've accepted an answer for every question I've posted (except for one open one)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try concatenating the value into the selector string.

```
$('.btns [data-dir="'+activeSlide+'"]')
```

Comment: I bet you meant `$(".btns button[data-dir="+activeSlide+"]")`

Comment: @JFK No, I quoted the value of `activeSlide` in the selector, either way works http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/X25sK/.

Comment: My holiday vacation was too long!  Concatenate, duh!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if "btns" it is a class, shouldn't it be
`$('.btns [data-dir=2]')`?